# Filter for checking session existence

Tags: java, servlets, struts, servlet-filters

I am developing a web application in Struts. I have a requirement that I have to check that a session exists for user. If the user session exists then user can access the resource, or I need to check session variable existence before accessing every JSP page.

For that I make use of filter where I check for the session variable existence. But when I use filter, every request is routed to that filter--even the login page request is routed to filter. The login page doesn't need the filter check applied, what to do for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is typical [session filter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Servletsessionfilter.htm) use case. For login page request, not to be filtered, you need have a different URL for login page which will be excluded in the URL mapping for the filter.

OR

In the filter itself, you can check what is the requested URL, its login page then don't check for the session. But I would recommend the earlier approach because its rightly address the [Separation of Concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) philosophy.